# PHP - Insert content at specific point in HTML

Tags: php

I have the following `<DIV>:`

```
<div class="general">

Some content here

</div>
```

I want to do a PHP include just before

Is this possible in PHP?

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php include "file.php"; ?>
<div class="general">

Some content here

</div>
```

Comment: I need to include it dynamically, I dont have acess to the source of the main content of the page only the header.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking...do you wish the replace the contents of the div with dynamically loaded content?  If so you would need to use AJAX.  Jquery is probably the easiest way to do this.